# Unable to call thrust on CUDA memory

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to find the sum of an array (already present in CUDA memory) using thrust library. Few replies here, said that is possible by wrapping it using thrust::device_ptr, but it is throwing an error for me.

Initial code

```
cudaMemcpy((void *)(data + stride), (void *)d_output, sizeof(unsigned int) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> vec((data + stride), (data + stride + (rows * cols)));
sum = thrust::reduce(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

The above code works perfectly fine. But if I change it to

```
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin(d_output);
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_output + stride + (rows * cols)));
sum = thrust::reduce(outputPtrBegin, outputPtrEnd);
```

It throws me the following error.

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
 what():  an illegal memory access was encountered
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks a lot for your time.

*Edited input from Robert Crovella
The mistake was using stride.
I have a following question (related to the above declaration)

Depending on the value of toggle, I need to call thrust

```
if(toggle) {
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin(d_output);
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_output + (rows * cols)));
}
else {
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin(d_X);
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_X + (rows * cols)));
}
```

But the compilation says outputPtrBegin and outputPtrEnd are not declared, because they are in the if statement. How do I declare these device pointers before and then use?

Comment: What is stride? In the initial code it looks like a byte offset. Is it?

Comment: Hi, Yes it's just an offset. Even when it is set to zero, I run into the same error.

Comment: "Even when it is set to zero, I run into the same error."  That's puzzling.  If so, my answer is not explaining the root cause of the issue, (although the sizes of your operations are clearly different).  It would be better if you provided a complete code.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually editing that comment. This code was in a while loop (incrementing values of stride in steps of (rows * cols)). The first iteration had run successfully (I had one more bug in printing values & it dint print the first printf when stride = 0, though the code had executed) Sorry once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_output + stride + (rows * cols)));
```

It should be:

```
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_output + (rows * cols)));
```

In your first (working) example, you are copying a region from the device to the host.  On the device, that region starts at `d_output` and has a length of `rows*cols` elements.  This is the data that you are ulimately passing through the `reduce` operation.  Yes, on the host, it happens to be copied to a region that begins at `data + stride` but that is irrelevant.  Ultimately you are performing a reduce over `rows*cols` elements, in your first implementation.

It's quite clear that in the second implementation, you are attempting to perform a reduce operation starting at `d_output` and going to `d_output+stride+(rows*cols)`.  This is not the same size operation.

In addition, you may want to do something like this instead:

```
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin(d_output);
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd = outputPtrBegin + (rows * cols);
sum = thrust::reduce(outputPtrBegin, outputPtrEnd);
```

Regarding your second question (please post new questions as new questions), instead of this:

```
if(toggle) {
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin(d_output);
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_output + (rows * cols)));
}
else {
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin(d_X);
    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd((d_X + (rows * cols)));
}
```

Do something like this:

```
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrBegin;
thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> outputPtrEnd;
if(toggle) outputPtrBegin=thrust::device_pointer_cast<unsigned int>(d_output);
else outputPtrBegin=thrust::device_pointer_cast<unsigned_int>(d_X);
outputPtrEnd = outputPtrBegin + (rows * cols);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a silly mistake from my end. 
I have one more question regarding the same. Have modified my question to reflect the same, can you please have a look at it when free?